# Assets from a shared project not rendered in design mode (XAML)

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, shared-project

I have a Windows Phone 8 Silverlight project and a Shared Project with some Assets (fonts, images, etc).

When I launch the emulator or deploy to the phone the content is correctly shown, but when I'm in design mode this content is not shown at all.

[image: Design mode] [image: Emulator]

This is how I set a custom font stored in the shared project to a TextBlock:

```
        <TextBlock Text="play" FontFamily="/Assets/fonts/BondoluoPeek.ttf#Bondoluo Peek"/>
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem once, turned out the designer was reading from some cached files. Try clearing cache, do a complete rebuild of the project with the given assets and then reload the designer.